# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CUSTOMER_IMPORT, Line 33 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CUSTOMER
    @LastName nvarchar(50) = NULL, 
    @FirstName nvarchar(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @LastName, @FirstName, 
    FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName
END
GO
```

Comment: There are more than one error there. But the error message is because of the comma after `@FirstName`: `SELECT @LastName, @FirstName FROM .....`

Comment: Thank you. But now it says:  Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Procedure CUSTOMER, Line 21
There is already an object named 'CUSTOMER' in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Is the comma!

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CUSTOMER
    @LastName nvarchar(50) = NULL, 
    @FirstName nvarchar(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @LastName, @FirstName
    FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks... Now it says:Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Procedure CUSTOMER, Line 21
There is already an object named 'CUSTOMER' in the database.

Comment: This happening because already exists an object named 'CUSTOMER' in your Database. Check for this, rename your procedure and the error will gone.